# How to set max pool size in MDB on weblogic 10.3

Tags: weblogic-10.x, message-driven-bean

I need to set the max pool size on a MDB on weblogic 10.3.

I inserted this annotation on MDB directly

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="MaxPoolSize", propertyValue="1")})
```

but it seems not to work.

Is there any other option to set?

Answer (score 7):

Try using weblogic [work manager](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_wls/self_tuned.html) settings to constrain the number of concurrent threads. The max-threads-constraint can be applied to a work manager set up for the specific MDB (or as part of a pool if you apply it to more than one bean)

so, for instance in weblogic-application.xml you'd have

```
<wls:work-manager>
  <wls:name>MyMDBWorkManager</wls:name>
  <wls:max-threads-constraint-name>MyMDBMaxThreads</wls:max-threads-constraint-name>
</wls:work-manager>
```

and applied to the beans in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml like so: (this works even when the MDB is annotated)

```
<wls:weblogic-enterprise-bean>
  <wls:ejb-name>MyMDB</wls:ejb-name>
  <wls:dispatch-policy>MyMDBWorkManager</wls:dispatch-policy>
</wls:weblogic-enterprise-bean>
```

The 'MyMDBMaxThreads' constraint can be specified in weblogic-application.xml, or directly in the WL Admin Console so it can be tuned on the fly.